# where can I download net.oauth httpclient4 jar file

Tags: java, maven, oauth, download

I need to give the link to our build engineer.

even though I added this to our pom file, it's not getting the jar.  thx
        
            net.oauth.core
            oauth-httpclient4
            20100601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The artifact is not in a central repository. You have to add the http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven/ repository into your pom.xml or deploy the artifact in your company's private repository.

Comment: @mosaad Today seems it is available here: http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/maven2/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem this fixed it

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth-httpclient4</artifactId>
        <version>20090913</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like it's older version. Not sure how important it is, though.

Comment: yes it is for an older project, i wrote this in case someone has the same problem